# MigLayout on split into 2 rows

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

I was wondering in using the Layout (MigLayout) could I split into 2 rows instead of two columns?

```
panel.add(fname,"split 2");
panel.add(Fname,"wrap, pushx, growx");
panel.add(lname,"split 2");
panel.add(Lname,"wrap, pushx, growx");
panel.add(desc,"split 3,top,gaptop 3,gapright 0.5");
panel.add(new JLabel("PlaceHolder"),"top,gaptop 3");
panel.add(new JScrollPane(Desc),"grow,push,wrap");
panel.add(C,"split 2, Right");
panel.add(D,"wrap");
```

I wanted the label "PlaceHolder" to be below the text description instead beside it 
is there a way to accomplish it? :)

[image]

Comment: Consider making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) with proper indentation.

Comment: use another row and make the scrollPane span it. BTW: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that shows a two-column layout with one label/field pair per row (at the top) and the two other labels below each other and to the left of a row spanning textArea:

```
MigLayout layout = new MigLayout("wrap 2, debug", "[][fill, grow]");
JComponent content = new JPanel(layout);
content.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
content.add(new JTextField());
content.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
content.add(new JTextField());
content.add(new JLabel("Description"));
content.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20, 20)), "spany 3");
content.add(new JLabel("placeholder"));
content.add(new JLabel(""), "newline"); // dummy to keep the placeholder at top
content.add(new JButton("Ok"), "span, split 2, align r, tag ok");
content.add(new JButton("Cancel"), "tag cancel");
```

Couple of thingies to note:

- always put as much configuration into the layout/row/column constraints as possible
- there's dummy label needed for [working around a possible bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11702050/203657)
- buttons are tagged to automatically comply to per-OS sizing and sequence guidelines

Comment: thank you for that but now I got a new problem http://prntscr.com/1qfuwj

is there a way so that they could be all on the top left? :)

Comment: don't understand your requirement, please edit your question and explain, best with a SSCCE